# Codeigniter how to convert date coding style onto this format

Tags: php

hi good day everyone i want to change my coding style with my date into this following format.

this is my echo date original code i want to change my style in coding.

```
<td class="<?php
           if (empty($log->philgeps_date)) {
           echo "noactioncell";
            }
            else
            {
                                              
             }
             ?> text-center align-middle" >
    
              <?php
              if (!empty($log->philgeps_date)) {
              echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($log->philgeps_date));
              }
              ?>
              </td>
```

this is the new code i want to use but i dont know how to declare if there is a echo date and to format with this code.

```
<td class="<?php echo empty($log->proc_mode) ? "noactioncell" :''; ?> text-center align-middle">
     <?php echo !empty($log->proc_mode) ? $log->proc_mode : '';?>
  </td>
```

Comment: Unable to get you. you want to add date formatting code __after__ `<?php echo !empty($log->proc_mode) ? $log->proc_mode : '';?>` __or what?__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should understand what the below code does:

```
<?php echo !empty($log->proc_mode) ? $log->proc_mode : '';?>
```

It checks if `$log->proc_mode` holds a not-null value. If yes, it prints that value otherwise an empty string will be printed.

What you're trying to achieve is, formatting the date into another format.

You can do something like:

```
<td class="<?php echo empty($log->philgeps_date) ? "noactioncell" :''; ?> text-center align-middle">
    <?php echo !empty($log->philgeps_date) ? date('m/d/Y', strtotime($log->philgeps_date)) : '';?>
</td>
```

Extra:

Since you're dealing with dates, it would be better to check if `$log->philgeps_date` is a valid date, rather than a `not-null check.

Comment: how about if its has a foreach sir  foreach($log->category as $c):
                                              echo $c->category_name."<br/>";
                                          endforeach;

Comment: if `philgeps_date` is a property of `$c`,you should change `$log->philgeps_date` to `$c->philgeps_date`. Otherwise, it should work as it is.

Comment: no this is different from philgeps date this for a for each of category name cause my web system can view a multiple category in the data table

Comment: Do a `print_r($log)`. You will know who the `$log` is structured. As I mentioned in the first part of the answer, the code just checks, if the `$log->philgeps_date` is set and not null. This will work for any variable. Also, read more about `echo` in PHP. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php